# SVG Codemirror completion

Tags: javascript, svg, codemirror

I'm trying to create SVG mode for CodeMirror (at least to have starting point). I've copied htmlmixed mode and replaced html with svg (since it's the same, only have different completion)

I've also removed all html tags and put this instead (in hints):

```
  var s = { attrs: {} }; // Simple tag, reused for a whole lot of tags

  var data = {
      svg: {
          attrs: {
              width: null, height: null, viewBox: null
          }
      },
      g: s
  };

  var globalAttrs = {
    id: null,
    'class': null,
    lang: ["en", "es"],
    style: null
  };
```

but when I type `<sv` or `<svg wid` and press <kbd>CTRL+Space</kbd> I've don't get completion. What I did wrong?

I'm creating editor from textarea:

```
var text = document.querySelector('textarea');
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(text, {
    mode:  "svg",
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
});
```

Here is my [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/REGvpo).

If I change mode to htmlmixed completion works.

Answer (score 1):

The `Codemirror.registerHelper("hint", name)` name parameter is not associated with the mode name. You can override the autocomplete function, and have it call `showHint`:

```
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
  CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.name) // name being the name you passed to registerHelper
}
```

Additionally, the callback for `Codemirror.registerHelper("hint", name, callback)` should return an object, not a function.

[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/samdenty99/pen/dwpLKE)

Comment: It works, but this just create more questions. Do you know if defaults auto completes are somehow encoded in CodeMirror? Or why do I need to monkey patch `CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete` and not use same code as the library, the code for html-hint.js don't overwrite autocomplete function, why it work and my don't? Do you know why? Or is just autocomplete not related command to completion and it just random name invoked on CTRL+Space? (I've found it in one the examples) If not that's not a problem will ask on GitHub.